# Dynamic Linq where clause throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

I am a novice at Linq and a true beginner with expression trees.

I have a generic expression routine that builds a simple Linq where clause that I found at:
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/dynamic-linq-queries-with-expression-trees/

```
public Func<TSource,bool> SimpleFilter<TSource> (string property, object value)
{
    var type = typeof(TSource);
    var pe = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyReference = Expression.Property(pe,property);
    var constantReference = Expression.Constant(value);
    var ret = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>
        (Expression.Equal(propertyReference, constantReference), new[] { pe });
    return ret.Compile();
}
```

When I call the function as `SimpleFilter("JobCustomerID", 449152)` it
yields `(p => p.JobCustomerId == 449152)` which is correct.

If I manually place that criteria in my Linq statement, I get the correct return.

```
var jj = db.VW_Job_List.Where((p => p.JobCustomerId == 449152));
```

However when called via the filter function, the Linq throws an `OutOfMemoryException`.
It is called in my application as:

```
var jj = db.VW_Job_List.Where(SimpleFilter<VW_Job_List>("JobCustomerID", 449152));
```

If I call the function with a text criterion, it returns properly:

```
var jj = db.VW_Job_List.Where(SimpleFilter<VW_Job_List>("CompanyCode", "LCS"));
```

Is there something specific about using an integer variable that needs to be accommodated? Do I have something coded incorrectly? Any thoughts or insights will be appreciated.

Comment: So you query database? If yes, how many rows are in VW_Job_List table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two calls

```
var jj = db.VW_Job_List.Where((p => p.JobCustomerId == 449152));
```

and

```
var jj = db.VW_Job_List.Where(SimpleFilter<VW_Job_List>("JobCustomerID", 449152));
```

are not equivalent. The first resolves to `Queryable.Where`, hence the filter is applied inside the database, while the second - to `Enumerable.Where`, thus causing loading the whole table in memory and applying the filter there.

The problem is that the **return type** of your `SimpleFilter` is `Func<TSource, bool>`. In order to make them equivalent, it should be `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`. Note that although they look visually the same, there is a huge difference between lambda expression and lambda delegate due to the different overload resolution when applied to `IQueryable<T>`.

So, change the method like this and try again:

```
public Expression<Func<TSource,bool>> SimpleFilter<TSource> (string property, object value)
{
    var type = typeof(TSource);
    var pe = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyReference = Expression.Property(pe,property);
    var constantReference = Expression.Constant(value);
    var ret = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>
        (Expression.Equal(propertyReference, constantReference), new[] { pe });
    return ret; // No .Compile()
}
```

Comment: Hummm interesting. I've never tought about the difference between using `Expression<...>` and not using it with EF

Comment: This may save my web applications from performance degradation. Thank you.